How to Read Batch Records Using a Named Tailer in ChronicleQueue?
Background:
I've been using a named Tailer to read messages from ChronicleQueue and track offsets. My current setup handles individual messages and keeps track of where we left off between restarts like this:
try (var tailer = queue.createTailer(consumerGroup)) {
    var ctx = tailer.readingDocument();
    if (ctx.isPresent()) {
        process(ctx.wire().read().object(DTO.class));
    }
ctx.close()
}

Need Help With:
Now, I want to shift to processing messages in batches and committing offsets the same way to boost efficiency. I'm looking for a way to tweak my Tailer to:
Handle batch processing of messages.
Commit offsets in batches so I can pick up right where I left off after a restart.
Any ideas on how to pull this off with ChronicleQueue?

I suggest;

creating the tailer once. You can do it once per process. NOTE: it's single-threaded and relatively expensive.
read as many messages as available, up to some batch size.
process this batch.
repeat.


How can I read more than one message from the queue? The method w.read().object(DTO.class) returns an object only once, even though I know there are more messages in the queue.
I came up with a solution using two trailers. Is this the correct approach?
